# My shortcode made from WP_Query display the post content without even rendering it in the shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I created a shortcode to display custom post type submissions in a list. The shortcode displaying the list perfectly.But the problem is below the list it shows the content of the post which is bottom of the list , which i dont expect that content to be shown.I only want the list to be displayed.
here is my code to create the short code

```
add_shortcode( 'property-list', 'slidermy' );
 function slidermy( $atts ) {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'post_type' => 'joelsa_realestates',
        'color' => 'blue',        
        'order' => 'ASC',       
    
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
      ob_start();
      ?>
      <style>
    *{
      color:#333333;
    }
    .feed-list{          
      width:100%;
      display: flex;         
      margin-top:20px;
      justify-content: stretch;         
      
    }
    .left-block{
     flex:1;
     position: relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     margin:0;
     border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
     border-radius:10px 0 0 0;     
    }       
   
    .right-block{
     flex:1;   
     padding:5px 10px;      
     display: flex;
     flex-direction:column;  
     align-items: flex-start;
     border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
     border-radius:0 10px 0 0; 
     position:relative;                             
    }
   
    .left-block a{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items:center;
      font-size:20px;
      font-weight:700;             
    }
    .img-slider{         
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
      flex-flow:row nowrap;
      translate: 0;
      transition:1s ease;
      border:none;
    }
    .img-slider img{
     flex:1;                
     object-fit:cover;        
    }
   
    .left-arrow{
      position:absolute;
      left:10px;
      top:40%;                
      width:35px;
      height:15%;         
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color:white;
      border:1px solid #333333;
      border-radius:2px;          
    }
    .right-arrow{
      position:absolute;
      right:10px; 
      top:40%;         
      width:35px;
      height:15%;         
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color:white;
      border:1px solid #333333;
      border-radius:2px;          
    }
   
    .just-added{
      padding:2px 6px;
      background-color:orange;
      color:white;
      font-size:15px;
      border-radius:5px;
      font-weight:bold;
      
    }
    .top-2-row{
      width:100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-top:15px;
      margin-bottom:15px;         
    }
    .icons-div span{
      margin-right:15px;
      color:#333333;
      font-size:18px;
      font-weight:500;
    }
    .icons-div span img{
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    .sale-price{
      color:#333333;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    .title{
      font-weight:700;
      font-size:medium;         
    }
    .location{     
      color:#222222;
      margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .listed-on{
      margin-top:20px;
      font-size:small;
    }
    .agent-row{
      width:100%;
      padding:5px;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
      border-top:1px solid #c1c1c1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items:center;

    }
    .agent-logo img{
      width:75px;
    }
  </style>
        
    <?php
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            
            $pid= get_the_ID();
            $publishedat= get_the_date('j F Y', get_the_ID());
            $banner_img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_banner_img', true);  
            $banner_img = explode(',', $banner_img);
            $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wporg_meta_key', true );
            $rent = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsa_re_rent', true );
            $sale_pricesuffix = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_salepricesuffix', true );
            $sale_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_saleprice', true );
            $property_contact_email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_contactemail', true );
            $joelsare_contacttele = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_contactphone', true );                              
            $location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_location', true );
            $bed_rooms= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_bedrooms', true );
            $bath_rooms= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_bathrooms', true );
            $reception_rooms= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_receptions', true );
            $agentlogo= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_agent_logo', true);              
        ?>
        <div class="feed-list">
          <div class="left-block" onmouseenter="displayArrows(<?=$pid?>)" onmouseleave="hideArrows(<?=$pid?>)">                
              <div class="img-slider" id="<?php echo 'img-slider'.$pid?>">
                  <?php                     
                  if(!empty($banner_img)) {
                    $counter = 0;
                   foreach ($banner_img as $attachment_id) {
                    $counter++;
                    if(wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id )==null)
                    {?>
                    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:grey;color:white;" onmouseenter="hideArrows(<?=$pid?>)">
                      <?php echo "No Images";?>
                    </div>
                      <?php
                    }
                    else{
                     ?>
                     <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );?>">
                     <?php 
                   }}}                                
                  ?>
              </div>
            <a href="javascript:void();" id="<?php echo 'left-arrow'.$pid?>" class="left-arrow" style="display:none;"  onclick="minusDivs(<?=$pid?>,<?=$counter?>)"><</a>
            <a href="javascript:void();" id="<?php echo 'right-arrow'.$pid?>" class="right-arrow" style="display:none;" onclick="plusDivs(<?=$pid?>,<?=$counter?>)">></a>              
          </div>
          <div class="right-block">
            <div class="top-1-row">
              <div class="just-added">just added</div>
            </div>
            <div class="top-2-row">
                <div class="sale-price">
                  <div><?=$sale_pricesuffix?></div>
                  <div> £ <?=$sale_price?></div>                     
                </div>
                <div class="icons-div">
                  <span><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/bedrooms.png'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"><?=$bed_rooms?></span>
                  <span><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/bathrooms.png'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"><?=$bath_rooms?></span>
                  <span><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/receptions.png'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"><?=$reception_rooms?></span>
                </div>
            </div>                    
            <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="location"><?=$location?></div>                
            <div class="short-desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <div class="listed-on">Listed on <?=$publishedat?></div>
            <div class="agent-row">
              <div class="agent-logo"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $agentlogo );?>"></div>
              <div class="agent-email"><?=$property_contact_email?></div>
              <div class="agent-tele"><?=$joelsare_contacttele?></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var transLateIndex = 0;              
            function minusDivs(div_id,counter) {
                var mintranslateIndex = (-100 * (counter-1));                
                var b = '<?php echo 'img-slider'?>'+ div_id;
                var leftarrow = '<?php echo 'left-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
                var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
                var n = -100 ;                       
           
                if(transLateIndex > mintranslateIndex){
                transLateDiv(transLateIndex += n,b);
                    document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "flex";                   
                }
                if(transLateIndex ==mintranslateIndex){                 
                    document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "none";                    
                }
            } 
          function plusDivs(div_id,counter) {
            var mintranslateIndex = (100 * (counter-1));
            var b = '<?php echo 'img-slider'?>'+ div_id;
            var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
            var n = 100 ;
                      
                if(transLateIndex < 0){                 
                transLateDiv(transLateIndex += n,b);                    
                }
                if(transLateIndex ==0){                 
                document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "flex";                   
                }         
            } 
          function displayArrows(div_id){          
                          
            var b = '<?php echo 'img-slider'?>'+ div_id;
            var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
            var leftarrow = '<?php echo 'left-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
                if(transLateIndex ==0){                   
                document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "flex";
                } 
           
                if(transLateIndex <0){                 
                document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "flex";
                document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "flex";
                }                                        
          }   
          
          function hideleftArrows(la){               
            document.getElementById(`${la}`).style.display = "hide";
           
          }
          function hideArrows(div_id){
            var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
            var leftarrow = '<?php echo 'left-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
            document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "none";              
          }
          function transLateDiv(n,b)
          {
          
            document.getElementById(`${b}`).style.translate = `${transLateIndex}%`;

          }
        </script>             
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>                    
 
<?php
        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $query; 

        the_posts_pagination(
            array(
                'mid_size' => '2',
                'prev_text' => 'Previous',
                'next_text' => 'Next',
                'screen_reader_text' => ' '
                )
        );
    ?>

<?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable;
}
}
```

excuse me my code is bit messy as it is not the final.
in front end when I put the short code
[property-list]
[short code in block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTa7j.png)
this is how it shows in front end.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGFk.jpg)

I appreciate someone can figure what is going wrong because i dont see the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason ,it was because where i put ob_start(); is wrong. Please see the correct code below

```
add_shortcode( 'joelsa-properties', 'joelsa_property_list' );

function joelsa_property_list(){
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3, 
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'post_type' => 'joelsa_realestates',
        'order' => 'ASC',
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  ob_start();
  while( $query->have_posts() ) {    
    $query->the_post();
    $pid= get_the_ID();
    $publishedat= get_the_date('j F Y', get_the_ID());
    $banner_img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_banner_img', true);  
    $banner_img = explode(',', $banner_img);
    $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wporg_meta_key', true );
    $rent = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsa_re_rent', true );
    $sale_pricesuffix = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_salepricesuffix', true );
    $sale_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_saleprice', true );
    $property_contact_email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_contactemail', true );
    $joelsare_contacttele = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_contactphone', true );                              
    $location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_location', true );
    $bed_rooms= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_bedrooms', true );
    $bath_rooms= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_bathrooms', true );
    $reception_rooms= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_receptions', true );
    $agentlogo= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_joelsare_agent_logo', true);   
    ?>
    <style>
        *{
          color:#333333;
        }
        .feed-list{          
          width:100%;         
          display: flex;         
          margin-top:20px;
          justify-content: stretch;    
        }
        .left-block{
         flex:1;
         position: relative;
         overflow:hidden;
         margin:0;
         border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
         border-radius:10px 0 0 0;     
        }       
        .right-block{
          flex:1;
          padding:5px 10px;      
          display: flex;
          flex-direction:column;
          justify-content:space-between;  
          align-items: flex-start;
          border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
          border-radius:0 10px 0 0; 
          position:relative;                             
        }     
        .left-block a{
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items:center;
          font-size:20px;
          font-weight:700;             
        }
        .img-slider{         
          display: flex;
          height: 100%;
          flex-flow:row nowrap;
          translate: 0;
          transition:1s ease;
          border:none;
        }
        .img-slider img{
         flex:1;                
         object-fit:cover;        
        }       
        .left-arrow{
          position:absolute;
          left:10px;
          top:40%;                
          width:35px;
          height:15%;         
          background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
          color:white;
          border:1px solid #333333;
          border-radius:2px;          
        }
        .right-arrow{
          position:absolute;
          right:10px; 
          top:40%;         
          width:35px;
          height:15%;         
          background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
          color:white;
          border:1px solid #333333;
          border-radius:2px;          
        }       
        .just-added{
          padding:2px 6px;
          background-color:orange;
          color:white;
          font-size:15px;
          border-radius:5px;
          font-weight:bold;
          
        }
        .top-2-row{
          width:100%;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          margin-top:15px;
          margin-bottom:15px;         
        }
        .icons-div span{
          margin-right:15px;
          color:#333333;
          font-size:18px;
          font-weight:500;
        }
        .icons-div span img{
          margin-right:5px;
        }
        .sale-price{
          color:#333333;
          font-size: 22px;
        }
        .title{
          font-weight:700;
          font-size:medium;         
        }
        .location{     
          color:#222222;
          margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        .listed-on{
          margin-top:20px;
          font-size:small;
        }
        .agent-row{
          width:100%;
          padding:5px;   
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items:center;        

        }
        .agent-logo img{
          width:75px;
        }
        .paginate{
          width:100%;
          margin:15px 0;
          text-align:center;         
          padding:5px;
        }
        .paginate ul li{
          display:inline;
          margin:20px;          
        }
        .paginate ul li a{
          color:#333333 !important;
          text-decoration:none;
        }
        .paginate ul li a:hover{
          color:#000000 !important;
          text-decoration:none;
        }
        .email-click{
          cursor: pointer;
          margin-right:5px;
                
        }
        .email-click:hover{        
          color:green;  
        }
        .call-click{
          cursor: pointer;
          margin-right:5px;
        }
        .call-click:hover{
          
          color:green; 
        }
        .agent-contacts{        
          padding:15px;
        }
        .email-click{
          margin:0 10px;
        }
        .call-click{
          margin:0 10px;
        }
   

        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          .feed-list{  
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center; 
          align-items:center;  
        }
        }
      </style>
<div class="feed-list">
  <div class="left-block" onmouseenter="displayArrows(<?=$pid?>)" onmouseleave="hideArrows(<?=$pid?>)">
     <div class="img-slider" id="<?php echo 'img-slider'.$pid?>">
        <?php                     
          if(!empty($banner_img)){
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($banner_img as $attachment_id) {
              $counter++;
              if(wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id )==null)
              {?>
                <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:grey;color:white;" onmouseenter="hideArrows(<?=$pid?>)">
                <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/images-coming-soon.jpg'; ?>" alt="" width="100%;height:100%;">
                </div>
              <?php
              }else{
                ?>
                  <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );?>">
                <?php 
                  }}}
                ?>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void();" id="<?php echo 'left-arrow'.$pid?>" class="left-arrow" style="display:none;"  onclick="minusDivs(<?=$pid?>,<?=$counter?>)"><</a>
      <a href="javascript:void();" id="<?php echo 'right-arrow'.$pid?>" class="right-arrow" style="display:none;" onclick="plusDivs(<?=$pid?>,<?=$counter?>)">></a>              
  </div>
  <div class="right-block">
    <div class="top-1-row">
      <div class="just-added">just added</div>
    </div>

    <div class="top-2-row">
        <div class="sale-price">
          <div><?=$sale_pricesuffix?></div>
          <div> £ <?=$sale_price?></div>                     
        </div>
        <div class="icons-div">
          <span><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/bedrooms.png'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"><?=$bed_rooms?></span>
          <span><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/bathrooms.png'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"><?=$bath_rooms?></span>
          <span><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/receptions.png'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"><?=$reception_rooms?></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="title"><?=get_the_title(); ?></div>

    <div class="location"><?=$location?></div> 

    <div class="short-desc"><?=get_the_excerpt(); ?></div>

    <div class="listed-on">Listed on <?=$publishedat?></div>

    <div class="agent-row">
      <div class="agent-logo"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $agentlogo );?>"></div>
      <div class="agent-contacts">
        <span class="email-span" id="email-span" style="display:none;"><?=$property_contact_email?></span>
        <span class="email-click" id="email-click" onclick="showEmail()"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/email-icon.jpg'; ?>" alt="" width="30px;height:auto;"></span>
        <span class="call-span" id="call-span" style="display:none;"><?=$joelsare_contacttele?></span>
        <span class="call-click" id="call-click" onclick="showTele()"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/images/call-icon.jpg'; ?>" alt="" width="25px;height:auto;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#email-click').click(function(){
    jQuery('#email-span').toggle('slow');
    jQuery('#call-click').toggle('slow');
   

    });
    jQuery('#call-click').click(function(){
    jQuery('#call-span').toggle('slow');
    jQuery('#email-click').toggle('slow');
   

    });

    });
</script>
<script>            
    var transLateIndex = 0;
    function minusDivs(div_id,counter) {
      var mintranslateIndex = (-100 * (counter-1));
      // alert( mintranslateIndex)
      var b = '<?php echo 'img-slider'?>'+ div_id;
      var leftarrow = '<?php echo 'left-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
      var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
      var n = -100 ; 
            
      // alert(b) 
      if(transLateIndex > mintranslateIndex){
        transLateDiv(transLateIndex += n,b);
        document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "flex";                   
        }
      if(transLateIndex ==mintranslateIndex){      
        document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "none";                    
        }
    
      // transLateDiv(b);                    
    } 
    function plusDivs(div_id,counter) {
      var mintranslateIndex = (100 * (counter-1));
      var b = '<?php echo 'img-slider'?>'+ div_id;
      var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
      var n = 100 ;
      // alert(b)             
      if(transLateIndex < 0){      
        transLateDiv(transLateIndex += n,b);                    
       }
      if(transLateIndex ==0){
        document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "flex";                   
      }
      // transLateDiv(b);
    }

    function displayArrows(div_id){
      var k =2;                  
      var b = '<?php echo 'img-slider'?>'+ div_id;
      var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
      var leftarrow = '<?php echo 'left-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
      if(transLateIndex ==0){
        // showleftArrows(leftarrow);  
        document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "flex";
      } 
      //alert(transLateIndex)
      if(transLateIndex <0){
        // showleftArrows(leftarrow);  
        document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "flex";
      }                          
  }   

  function hideleftArrows(la){
      //alert(la)
      document.getElementById(`${la}`).style.display = "hide";    
  }
  function hideArrows(div_id){
    var rightarrow = '<?php echo 'right-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
    var leftarrow = '<?php echo 'left-arrow'?>'+ div_id;
    document.getElementById(`${leftarrow}`).style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById(`${rightarrow}`).style.display = "none";              
  }
  function transLateDiv(n,b)
  {
    // alert(b)
    document.getElementById(`${b}`).style.translate = `${transLateIndex}%`;
  }
</script>     
    <?php    
  }
  
  // Restore original Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  <nav class="paginate">
    <ul>
        <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $query->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
        <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $query->max_num_pages) ?></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  <?php
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();    
  return $output;  
  


}
```